# Enable-Migrations Not Working Because of the Windows on Mac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget-package, migrate

I am a Mac user but want to develop with C# via Visual Studio. Therefore, I have a *Parallels* account which is a programme for switching OS to the Windows while using it.

Firstly, let me introduce the error I am getting: (Trying to do it from the Package Manager Console inside of the NuGet Package Manager)

> Cannot determine a valid start-up project. Using project
>   'CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample' instead. Your configuration file and
>   working directory may not be set as expected. Use the
>   -StartUpProjectName parameter to set one explicitly. Use the -Verbose switch for more information.
>
> Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1"
>   argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
>   'file://\Mac\Home\Desktop\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\E
>   ntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \Mac\Home\Desktop\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:62
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   \Mac\Home\Desktop\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:50
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could
>   not load file or
>   assembly 'file://\Mac\Home\Desktop\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample\packages\EntityFramework.6.1
>   .3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \Mac\Home\Desktop\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:31
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

VS2015 is currently downloaded on my system. I have a model class and a local database but from now on I want to be able to change the database via the migrations. However, I'm having trouble with achieving it and I think the reason behind is the fact Windows is in on Mac as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938987/how-do-i-enable-migrations-in-the-package-manager-console) suggests. I thought in that way because when I wanted to access my Visual Studio Projects on Windows system, I entered into from the directory named *Home on 'Mac'(Y:)* under *Network Location* (The exact path I followed is Computer->Home on 'Mac'(Y:)[Under Network Location tab]->Documents->Visual Studio 2015). Again, as the answer in the question the suggests, I cut it and paste to the Desktop of my Windows system. But later I realized, I am only able to reach Desktop from Network Locations tab in the Computer directory.

I hope anyone had the same trouble before and solved so he can help me about it.

Waiting for your good answers,

Thanks,

Comment: And you seriously think that the MacOS Hypervisor-Host has ANYTHING to do with it?

Comment: Well, maybe as I said, I thought. But you are right, it might not be, so I changed the title.

Comment: I think this question actually IS related to OSX and Paralells, because it works with network folders. If the question is specific about having projects in network folders, then it's a duplicate question as it's answered in the link. Imo it would be much more usefull to let the question title about OSX and Paralells to let other people with same problem as you and me find an answer faster

Comment: I am confused hahah but yeah I think so, I will make inital. That will help others much I guess

Comment: Yeah, it was really about it. Problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same configuration (OSX + Parallels) and had the same problem than you. When source code is on OSX shared folder EF Package Manager Console throws that message. And as your link states, the problem is not Mac+Parallels but having the code on a network location.

If you move the code to your VM's desktop, maybe it's still network location if Paralells is configured to share desktop between Mac and Windows. Just try some pure windows location, as C:\VsProjects

I ended up moving the code to Windows location, it worked much better for me, but if you want to keep the code on network folder just need to use -StartupProjectName and specify the executable project there explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry that I just saw your answer. Will try it right away then let you know whether it works or not

Comment: I think it now worked. But warn me with saying as "Detected database created with a database initializer. Scaffolded migration '201602062250118_InitialCreate' corresponding to existing database. To use an automatic migration instead, delete the Migrations folder and re-run Enable-Migrations specifying the -EnableAutomaticMigrations parameter." Is it alright do you think? Also I wonder if it is wise to change export import settings to this path?

Comment: This is another question, please ask it as a new one. Regards!

Comment: This worked well for me.  Thanks for posting.  I had no idea it would be due to Parallels, but you were right!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the DataAccessLayer project was not being identified. I had to specifically specify the `-ProjectName` and then the migration worked.

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <Project>.DataAccessLayer -StartUpProjectName <Project>.WebApi -Verbose
```